# Why is the payment gateway not opening my android app with an App Link?

Tags: android, redirect, payment-gateway, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I'm implementing an Android app that uses a payment gateway which opens up in the browser. Once the payment completes the payment gateway should automatically redirect to the successful payment URL that I specified. However, currently, this redirect is not opening my Android App but instead redirecting in the browser.

So my question is, are there specific scenarios that result in Android using the App Link to open the app? Something like a property that needs to be set on the anchor tag or similar? From the documentation on App Links it seems like nothing special should be needed, as they state that the app becomes the default handler for that URL https://developer.android.com/training/app-links.

The payment gateway web page is provided by the payment provider, so I can't modify it. However, in an attempt to test opening the app using the App Link, I tried to make my own custom web page with buttons and anchor tags containing the App Link. But none of these launched the app either.

This is what my app's manifest entry looks like to configure the App Link

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="5d1a-196-251-220-14.ngrok-free.app"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

I also have https://5d1a-196-251-220-14.ngrok-free.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json set up, and it appears to be verified as expected:

[image]

Running the following command also successfully opens the app at the expected path:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://5d1a-196-251-220-14.ngrok-free.app/paymentSucceeded"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As far as I can tell everything is in place to allow the app link to work correctly, so I'm wondering if I might be misunderstanding when App Links will actually open the app.

Comment: What link are you using?  There's a MAJOR difference between clicking a URL in a browser and sending a VIEW intent.  The second will open your app, assuming the host matches.  The first generally will not-  browsers tend to follow links within the browser itself.  Chrome has a special url format you can use to force a deep link to an app, but that may or may not work in other browsers.  This is also affected by device settings and Android version, as this behavior has been tweaked over time.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks for your response. I'm using the link mentioned above, https://5d1a-196-251-220-14.ngrok-free.app/paymentSucceeded, via the browser. I suspect you might have answered my question. So unless a link is specifically marked on the website as a deep link, then the browser won't allow a redirect to the app?

Answer (score 0):

This has always been a little tricky and we have used https://www.branch.io/ in the past to do the deep linking.
I am curious though why you are taking the focus away from your application and presenting a payment screen in the browser.
If you are sending the payment information directly to your provider, you can embed this in your application and still stay out of higher PCI compliance.
We integrate USIO’s Checkout platform (https://checkout.usiopay.com/2.0/documentation/) in our mobile app. They have a web UI, but it is also easy to do it directly in the app and keep the experience seamless.